# Why is there a provision of pressure setting in GPS?

Tags: altitude, gnss, qnh

Some of the GPS have a provision of setting barometric pressure (QNH/QFE). How does it work?

Comment: Welcome to the site, can you post an actual model so we know what you're talking about?

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14789/62)

Answer (score 2):

By either manually entering the indicated altitude, total air temperature, barometric pressure, etc., or feeding those variables via sensors connected to the GNSS unit, it is able to know the true airspeed, wind direction/speed and the head/tail wind components.

Very useful for knowing the performance in-flight.

Example interface for the [Garmin GTN 650/750 series with software 4.10](https://static.garmin.com/pumac/190-01007-11_0A_Web.pdf):

---

[image]